# Common table expressions- recursive call

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this piece of code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER-2008)

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
AS
(
SELECT STATEMENT = CAST('I Like ' AS VARCHAR(300)), LEN('I Like ')
UNION ALL
SELECT
CAST(STATEMENT + 'CodeProject! ' AS VARCHAR(300))
, LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
WHERE LENGTH < 300
)
SELECT STATEMENT FROM ShowMessage
```

Output:

[image]

I can't get the meaning of the code correctly, especially the usage of length.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the query results when you change it to include the LENGTH column.

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
AS
(
    SELECT  STATEMENT = CAST('I Like ' AS VARCHAR(300)), 
            LEN('I Like ')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CAST(STATEMENT + 'CodeProject! ' AS VARCHAR(300)), 
            LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
    WHERE   LENGTH < 300
)
SELECT  STATEMENT,
        LENGTH
FROM    ShowMessage
```

You will notice on each recursion the length of the string gets longer.

The recursice loops will end once the leng grows to longer than 300